# Error at Linked list (java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I created my own linked list, but when I tried to run it there is an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at List.add(List.java:8)  //if(t.val ==null)
at main.main(main.java:38) //linput.add(inputLine.split(" ")[i]);
```

Here is my List class:

```
class List{
    String val;
    List next=null; 
    private List t; 

    public void add(String word){   
        if(t.val ==null)
            t.val=word;
        else while(!t.next.val.equals(null))
        {
            t=t.next;
            if(t.next.val.equals(null))
            {
                t.next.val=word;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public int get(String word)
    {   
        int i=0;
        if(t.val.equals(word))
            i=0;
        else while(!t.next.val.equals(word))
        {
            t=t.next;
            i++;
            if(t.next.val.equals(word))
            {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }

    public String indexOf(int i)
    {   
        int counter=0;
        while(counter<i)
        {
            t=t.next;
            counter++;
        }
        return t.val;
    }

}
```

And here is my main function :

```
static public void main(String[] args)  
{   
    List linput = new List();
    String inputLine = "Hey look at me.";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < inputLine.split(" ").length ; i++)
    {
        linput.add(inputLine.split(" ")[i]);

    }
    System.out.println(linput.indexOf(0)+" "+linput.indexOf(1)+" "+linput.indexOf(2));
}
```

I initialized t but next time there is an error like this:

```
private List t =new List();

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at List.<init>(List.java:5)
    at List.<init>(List.java:5)
    at List.<init>(List.java:5)
```

Sorry. I can't give my full code, because the rest of my code is working well (reading from txt etc....).

Comment: Did you initialize your `private List t;` variable in your `List` class. Because it looks like you aren't.

Comment: Your list `t` is null by the time it reached this line - `if(t.val ==null)`

Comment: Looks to me like `t` is `null` and the test `if(t.val == null)` is throwing the NPE.

Comment: Hmm.I initialized  t but next time there is an error like this:
private List t =new List(); 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at List.<init>(List.java:5)
 at List.<init>(List.java:5)
 at List.<init>(List.java:5)

Comment: i cant use any collection class or its subclasses.

Comment: i didnt use that List . i created my own List class. and point of the not using collection class is learning the working of data structures.

Comment: Now I see the problem. You defined a class named List and tried to initialize a List member variable of that same class. That would cause infinite calls to the constructor of List.

Comment: Exactly.Soooo what should i do ?

Comment: You could use lazy instantiation: to access t, replace the t variables by getT(). In getT(), check if t is null. If it is, create a new List and assign it to t. Return t.

Comment: Given that you are assigning an instance of `List` in the constructor of `List` how do you think that would not result in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be related to the variable 't' (i.e., private List t). 
Did you initialize this variable ? The if (t.val == null) seems to be cribbing this as t is null (uninitialized) at this point
You should have allocated object (using new) for this variable.

Can you share the full code for the constructor of List ?

Comment: By giving us full List Class, i guess he uses the std ctor

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to implement a simple forward list, rather than use the Java `LinkedList class`, you need to:

- Change your implementation of the list to reference nodes in the list
- handle traversal of the linked nodes in your word list

Here is an example:

**WordList class**

```
package com.example.words;
class WordList {

    private WordNode head = null;
    private int listSize = 0;

    public void add(String word) {
        // TODO add check for duplicate word
        if (head == null) {
            head = new WordNode();
            head.setValue(word);
            listSize++;
        } else {
            WordNode current = head;
            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            WordNode newNode = new WordNode();
            newNode.setValue(word);
            current.setNext(newNode);
            listSize++;
        }
    }

    public int getWordIndex(String word) {
        WordNode current = head;
        int index = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while (!found && current != null) {
            found = current.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(word);
            if (!found) {
                index++;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            return index;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public String indexOf(int i) {
        int index = 0;
        WordNode current = head;
        if (i <= listSize) {
            while (index < i) {
                current = current.getNext();
                index++;
            }
            return current.getValue();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public int size() {
        return listSize;
    }
}
```

**WordNode Class**

```
package com.example.words;

public class WordNode {
    private String value;
    private WordNode next = null;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public WordNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(WordNode link) {
        next = link;
    }

}
```

**Test Driver**

```
package com.example.words;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TODO handle punctuation
        WordList myList = new WordList();
        String inputLine = "Hey look at me.";

        String[] pieces = inputLine.split(" ");


        for (int i=0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            myList.add(pieces[i]);
        }

        for (int i=0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            String value = myList.indexOf(i);
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(pieces[i])) {
                System.out.println("Following node is wrong:");
            }
            System.out.println ("node " + i + ". = " + value);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When i tried to initiliaze it i am recieving java.lang.StackOverflowError at List.<init>(List.java:5) at List.<init>(List.java:5)

Comment: The question is HOW do you init it ;)

Comment: Like this : private List t =new List();

Answer (score 0):

You tried to create `t` as a member variable of its own class like this:

```
class List {
    [...]
    private List t = new List();
    [...]
}
```

This won't work because the constructor of `List` would be called indefinitely.

Try lazy instantiation of `t` instead. Replace all access of `t` with a getter:

```
private List getT() {
    if (this.t == null) {
        this.t = new List();
    }
    return t;
}
```